# Disabling EsLint For Single File Not Working

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, eslint

I have a VueJS project initialized using Webpack, with Eslint enabled.

I'm trying to disable it for a file using the tag...

```
/* eslint-disable */
```

...at the top of the file.

It's not working.

I've tried other combinations:

```
/*eslint-disable no-alert, no-console */

/* eslint-disable no-alert */
```

It still isn't disabling at the file level?

Is this something I need to disable at the Webpack config file?

Is there some simpler way to disable at the file level?

Comment: Can you add a snippet of the file that's giving you errors and the error output that you're getting?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and ended up adding the file to the .eslintignore file in the project root folder